# AngularJS: Increment input's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button and an input in html:

```
<button ng-click="addQuantity()" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">+</button>
<input readonly type="text" value="{{ quantity || 1 }}" class="form-control totalQuantity pull-right"></input>
```

And the AngularJS code:

```
$scope.addQuantity = function(id){

}
```

I just want to increment the input.value (which default is 1), with every click on the button. I would to it by myself, but I don't know the most efficient way to do it.

**If you have any hints for me, please share.** Thank you!

**Edit**
The `id` is the `id` from ng-repeat:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="(id, product) in itemsToBuy">
```

The input is added with every repeat of li element.

**Edit2:** There's a fiddle with whole app: https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button ng-click="addQuantity(id)" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">+</button>
<input readonly type="text" value="{{product.quantity || 1}}" class="form-control totalQuantity pull-right"/>
```

Pass the id which serves as an array index to identify exact product in the addQuantity.

And just simply increment the quantity. If quantity is undefined - it is equal to 1, otherwise - increment

```
$scope.addQuantity = function(id){
    if(!$scope.itemsToBuy[id].quantity){
       $scope.itemsToBuy[id].quantity = 1;
    }else{
        $scope.itemsToBuy[id].quantity++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to have access to this `li(id).value`. And by the way, quantity is not defined.

Comment: Ok, then leave the expression in the value. If quantity is not defined, please provide us with the data structure you are using in this case. P.S. I've updated the answer

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/12/ It also did not work because there was a missing reference to the product object. product.quantity

Comment: Bro, is there a way to fix this that I have to click double to make it increment? I want to  click once and add+1.

Comment: Updated https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/13/ At the moment, if the quantity is undefined you display 1, and when you press the button it is set to 1. I've changed that if the quantity is undefined, then it is zero. When you press the button then it is incremented by 1.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the 1 to be the default amount. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126406/discussion-between-patrickkx-and-operatorius).

Comment: You have to initialize the quantity to be equal to 1 in each product. It is only displayed as 1 but it is not stored in the object. Otherwise you will face the issue with "clicking twice" or you will have to initialize the value before posting this form to the server since if the quantity was not incremented - it is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Just increment the $scope variable by 1

```
 <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in itemsToBuy">
    <input readonly type="text" value="{{product.quantity}}" class="form-control totalQuantity pull-right">
    <button ng-click="addQuantity(product)" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">+</button>
  </li>
```

**Controller**

```
   $scope.addQuantity = function(item){
    item.quantity +=1;    
  };
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4HRazUm4HcARyvS8nksD?p=preview)**

Comment: I think that id means the id of the product he wants to increment

Comment: Edited my post about the id.

Comment: It works in your fiddle, but it doesn't increment the quantity in my app. I dont know why... take look at my app, I put link jsfiddle in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should send the product directly... like this

```
$scope.addQuantity = function(product){
    product.quantity += 1
}
```

and this would solve your problem.